# How to add conditional logic to an Oracle query?

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle query :

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.function_id "functionID",
  TABLE1.function_file_name "function_file_name",
  NVL(TABLE1.parameters, '') "sParams",
  NVL(TABLE3.amount, 0) "function_amount",
  NVL(TABLE2.FREE, 0) "free",
  TABLE4.customer_id "customer_id",
  TABLE4.user_name "user_name"
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
  ON TABLE1.function_id = TABLE2.function_id
INNER JOIN TABLE4
  ON TABLE2.customer_user_id = TABLE4.customer_user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3
  ON TABLE3.function_id = TABLE1.function_id
  AND NVL(TABLE3.start_date, SYSDATE) <= SYSDATE
  AND NVL(TABLE3.end_date, SYSDATE) >= SYSDATE
WHERE function_name = 'Func1'
AND TABLE4.user_userid = 'TEST1'
```

which will return me the below output:
[image]

I have to add conditional logic here.

If the above query returns data then I have to set the query result to below variables:

```
•   functionId 
•   functionFilename 
•   functionParams 
•   isFree 
•   chargeAmount   
•   customerId 
•   customerUserName
```

or else I have to return an error.

I am new to Oracle.

Comment: *"variables"* implies you are writing a client program to run the query. What language are you using? PL/SQL stored procedure? Something else?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want the columns names to be the paramaters's list just change, the aliases names in the query itself. That will display the wanted names when there is data to retrieve. If you want to raise an error you can use the no_data_found oracle exception. I preffer you to read in the net about Plsql exceptions handle.

Comment: @APC : I am using PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

You should use [cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/explicit_cursor.htm#LNPLS01313).
Example for your query:

```
declare 
  cursor cur1 is
SELECT
  TABLE1.function_id as "functionID",
  TABLE1.function_file_name as "function_file_name",
  NVL(TABLE1.parameters, '') as "sParams",
  NVL(TABLE3.amount, 0) as "function_amount",
  NVL(TABLE2.FREE, 0) as "free",
  TABLE4.customer_id as "customer_id",
  TABLE4.user_name as "user_name"
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
  ON TABLE1.function_id = TABLE2.function_id
INNER JOIN TABLE4
  ON TABLE2.customer_user_id = TABLE4.customer_user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3
  ON TABLE3.function_id = TABLE1.function_id
  AND NVL(TABLE3.start_date, SYSDATE) <= SYSDATE
  AND NVL(TABLE3.end_date, SYSDATE) >= SYSDATE
WHERE function_name = 'Func1'
AND TABLE4.user_userid = 'TEST1';
row1 cur1%rowtype;

begin
  OPEN cur1;
  FETCH cur1 INTO row1;
  CLOSE cur1;

  if row1.functionID is null then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Your Error!'); 
  end;
end;
```